# Would landing on mars during a storm considerably increase atmospheric drag?

Tags: mars, landing, reentry, atmospheric-drag, weather

Any chance we could harvest all those dust particles for an significant improvement in aero-breaking capabilities or would it destroy most heat-shields?

[image: estimated visibility]

Comment: I would appreciate some explanation about the image, does it show a dust storm on Mars?

Comment: @Uwe no it's a simulation. See for example https://www.npr.org/2018/06/13/619573721/enormous-dust-storm-on-mars-threatens-the-opportunity-rover

Comment: it is indeed a simulated point of view for the curiosity rover, made by NASA using the data from visibility measurements by the rover. Original picture is here: https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA22521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest models, drag is directly linearly proportional to density, i.e. doubling drag would require doubling the air density.

Based on terrestrial flying experience:  any material that can be suspended in a mixture (i.e. water droplets forming clouds, or ash/dust particles also forming clouds) isn't significantly changing the density of the containing medium.  If it did, the air would tend to separate out over top of the dust.  As-is, wind is capable of keeping the particles suspended.

So no, my (admittedly SWAG) conclusion is that you won't see an improvement in aero-braking.

Sandblasting effect I don't have a good guess at.  Presumably at high entry speeds the entry shock would be pushing most of the dust around the vehicle, but I have no idea at what point the dust could become a problem.